# Get error Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:344 if I try to publish port

Tags: docker

I am new to docker and I am following the tutorial
https://github.com/docker/labs/blob/master/beginner/chapters/webapps.md

After I have build my image (named expose-static), I can run 
docker run expose-static

However, if I do something like this to publish port:

```
docker run expose-static -p 5000:5000
```

It fails and gives the error:

```
C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:344: starting container process caused "exec: \"-p\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.
```

This is the console output if I do `docker ps`

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
9f8c404eadf4        expose-static       "/bin/sh -c 'cd /usr…"   2 minutes ago       Up 2 minutes        80/tcp, 5000/tcp    <some_name_I_dunno>
```

content of my Dockerfile

```
FROM nginx
EXPOSE 5000
ENV AUTHOR=Docker

WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY Hello_docker.html /usr/share/nginx/html

CMD cd /usr/share/nginx/html && sed -e s/Docker/"$AUTHOR"/ Hello_docker.html > index.html ; nginx -g 'daemon off;'
```

Answer (score 8):

Instead of doing

```
docker run expose-static -p 5000:5000
```

Doing

```
docker run -p 5000:5000 expose-static
```

will not run into problem

Comment: Even though this works, i would appreciate more if i'd know why.

Comment: This actually solves so much more. In my case, running a Sanic microservice with docker run <name> -p 8000:8000 made the service to refuse to connect to browsers (even if it ran correctly). Everything failed until I did what this SO answers suggests, i.e. inverse image name with port mapping